# How do you make a variable change from one class to another in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am building a simple game using Kivy. I have two classes, Result() and Game(), where both are inheriting from 'Screen'. The Game Class has a function that calculates the the result of the game and produces a message which I want to display on the Result Screen which contains a label and the screen gets displayed after the result is calculated.
My KV file:

```
<Result>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Result Screen"
        Label:
            id: result_label
```

Using the id of the Label, 'result_label', I thought using would work `

```
Result().ids.result_label.text = "message"
```

`
I tried confirming this using:

```
print(Result().ids)
```

And yes it tells me that indeed the id does exist and so i expected that the previous block of code would change the text of the label to "message", but it just shows a Label with no text, and there is no error. So how would you change the text of a label from outside the class?

Comment: Using `Result().ids` creates a new instance of `Result`, and references the `ids` of that new instance. That new instance is not the one that appears in your GUI. Not enough information to determine the correct way to access the the correct instance of `Result`. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your response, it helped me solve the issue. It cleared up my understanding of my own code too. I used ScreenManager's get_screen to get the correct instance of the class and it worked as expected!